# How to assert two different expectations in playwright?

Tags: testing, playwright

I'm testing for two different Text contents in playwright.

Once a user selects a particular option, I have to go back to the main page and check the text content.
I already have an if statement for the particular option, but I need help with asserting the expectation for the text contents.
Here's my test:

```
async verifyParticipantEligibility() {
  
  expect (await this.participantStatus.textContent()).toBe('Screened - Ineligible')
  expect (await this.participantStatus.textContent()).toBe('Can be re-screened') 
}
```

I've tried this below:

```
async verifyParticipantEligibility() {
  // requires if statement - using above. 
  expect (await this.participantStatus.textContent()).toBe('Screened - Ineligible')
  expect (await this.participantStatus.textContent()).toBe('Can be re-screened') 
}
```

This searches for the first naturally, how do you assert two different text contents in playwright?

Comment: Are you trying to assert inside 2 if conditions separately in two different places? Or inside a single assertion want to assert either one of them?

Comment: If they are inside two separate IF conditions then you can simply put your both expect statements inside the if conditions as is.

Comment: Why not use a [web first assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions)? This may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). There's no way to manipulate the app such that exactly one of these two conditions is true? Maybe you could add a bit of context as to why this requirement makes sense for your app.

Comment: So essentially, the issue is if a user clicks one condition, one the central page it'll display  Screened-Ineligible, if a user clicks the other condition, on the central page, it'll display 'Can be re-screened', not sure if an if statement can be used for this as it's on a completely different page to the page where the user selects the condtions.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that with a regex checking for one string or the other:

```
expect (await this.participantStatus.textContent())
  .toHaveText(/Screened - Ineligible|Can be re-screened/)
```